# PHP Curl, Collection + JSON Response for specific field

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm messing with the teamsnap API which uses Collection + JSON which seems to be making it a bit more difficult to extract specific data (at least for me).

What I need to do is get each member id so I can loop through those to then get a JSON response for each member's info.  So far I am working on the first step.

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php 
$url = "https://api.teamsnap.com/v3/members/search?team_id=TEAMID";
$access_key = 'TOKEN';
$request = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_key ) );
$response = (string)curl_exec( $request );
curl_close($request);

$result = json_decode($response, true);
foreach ($result as $r) {
echo $r['id'];
}
?>
```

**UPDATE:**  I used print_r without json_decode and went line by line through thousands of lines of resposne to see how exactly the information I actually want is coming back.  This is a bit the relevant portion.  Sorry to have led you on a wild goose chase, but the response is quite complicated when it comes back and half of it is examples of how data COULD be returned....

```
{
    "collection":{
    "items":[
{
"href":"https://api.teamsnap.com/v3/members/MEMBERID",
"data":[
"name":"id",
"value":MEMBERID
},
{
"name":"type",
"value":"member"
},
{
"name":"address_city",
"value":""
},
{
"name":"address_state",
"value":""
},
{
"name":"address_street1",
"value":""
},
{
"name":"address_street2",
"value":null
},
{
"name":"address_zip",
"value":""
},
```

Comment: since your api is not open for public, can you edie your post and provide a completed return $response structure (not necessary the complete data)? Please also specify the data is from $response or from $result.

Comment: See my answer in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data you provided is from `$response`. The data structure does not provide an easy way to parse the data. In order to get to the `'name':'id'` value pair. Do this:

```
$result = json_decode($response);
foreach ($result->collection->items as $items=>$val) {
    foreach ($val->data as $data=>$datasets) {
        foreach ($datasets as $dataset=>$val) {
            echo $dataset.': '.$val;
            echo "<br>";  
        }
    }
};
```

It will return the results as:

```
name: id
value: 3745306
name: type
value: user
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I am getting a php error:  invalid argument for foreach;  I have updated the JSON string to be what I actually am getting from the response, the previous was what the API said it would be.

Comment: Based on your revised post, the data structure changed, and the way to get to the name field therefore changed, and my previous answer no longer work due to that. See my new answer for how to get the data out.

Comment: After making some edits on my part, this works!  How would I now echo only the value of specific id's?

Comment: I think you need to get a better understanding of object and associated array. You can access to an object easily using the `foreach` to travel down to the deeper level until it no longer has an object structure (`{ .. }`), in this case , `data` is an array consists of a series of objects. To get to a particular element of an array, you use something like `$dataset[$i]['name']`, this will get you the 'id', so you may need to change the inner `foreach` loop to a `for ($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++)`, this will allow you to access a particular set of data with the index `$i`.

Comment: One more comment, the `json_decode($response, true)` will return an object which is more convenience for travel down using `foreach`. 'json_decode($response)` will return in an array, which is easier to access the data like $result['collection']['data']`, see which way is more comfortable and easier for you and fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edited data structure, the answer that I provided on my previous post no longer work. Here is the one based on your revised data structure:

```
$result=json_decode($response);
foreach($result->collection->template->data as $dataset) {
    foreach($dataset as $key=>$val) {
        echo $key.": ".$val;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this is almost there!  It only returns the first set, not all of the members.  How can we loop through the arrays deeper?

Comment: I once again updated the response using print_r.  I have added the updates in the above for your review.